# Vue 2 + TypeScript: Avoid mutating Prop directly - in a class based component with vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to be able to declare my Prop, using vue-property-decorator, in a class based component, without having to initialize the property.

I'm backed into a corner:

1. If I don't initialize, TypeScript doesnt compile:

> "TS2564   (TS) Property 'parentData' has no initializer and is not
>   definitely assigned in the constructor."

2. If I do initialize, VueJS throws a warning at runtime:

> "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders."

What I have below works, but the warning is quite annoying and also makes me think there is a better way to do it:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Client } from '../../../../domainmodels/client';

@Component({})
    export default class SearchLocationsComponent extends Vue {

         @Prop() 
         parentData: Client = new Client();

    }


My dependencies:   
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^5.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not initializing a property during the construction phase, you should explicitly indicate that it could be undefined:

```
parentData: Client | undefined;
```

For assigning default value for `@Prop` decorated member, you should use decorator's `default` parameter:

```
@Prop({ default: () => new Client}) 
parentData: Client | undefined;
```

Or, as **not recommended** option, you can add `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` to your typescript compiler options.

**Update 1:**

Most suitable workaround for such case is to use `definite assignment assertion modifiers`, introduced in typescript 2.7. Combining it with default `Prop` decorator initialization should do the trick:

```
@Prop({ default: () => new Client }) 
parentData!: Client;
```

Comment: Thing is, parentData can never be undefined, due to the way that property is passed in from the Parent. Explicitly stating it could be undefined forces me to place checks for it being undefined everywhere I use it - which clutters the code unnecessarily. Suppose I do put the default value in, as well as the undefined potential, this doesn't make sense to me - it'll always at least be a new Client() and therefore never undefined - right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated the answer with workaround for your case.

Answer (score 3):

maybe I'm a little bit late, but if you are writing Vue in Typescript, you may want to use `PropSync` instead of `Prop` that `vue-property-decorator` provides.

So for example you have the following:

```
@Prop() propArrayName!: type[];
```

instead you can use:

```
@PropSync('propArrayName', { type: Array }) _localArrayVariable!: type[];
```

this way you avoid mutating Prop() but instead the prop is computed()... you can read more here:

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-propsyncpropname-string-options-propoptions--constructor--constructor---decorator